# Let K/F be a transcendental extension , then does every F-homomorphism has to be an automorphism?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I have figured out that if $K/F$ be an algebraic extension , then does every F-homomorphism need not be an automorphism .

But I can't figure it out for  in thee trasncendental case.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $X \mapsto X^2$ is an $F$-algebra endomorpishm of $K=F(X)$ that is not an automorphism.